# Is there a certain size where bugs are not required to be checked?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

Is there a certain size that bugs don’t have to be checked anymore because they’re too small and if yes what is the size? And what is the source of this size?

Comment: The question is, when we say a bug is too small to need to be checked, do we mean it is not identifiable as a bug but you can see a speck there, or do we mean you can't see anything there at all. If the latter, that is an issue, because the human eye is capable of seeing a speck down to about 1/10th of the width of a human hair.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan,_Yoreh_De'ah_84.36

Comment: Seemingly you should really be asking a size whereby you can eat it. Checking just follows from a prohibition on consumption

Comment: related (duplicate)?: [How do we determine whether a dish is clean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45985/11501)